# how to get selected button value into the input text box to bind values angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get selected button values into text box ? if i change text in input box, have to bind that text to the button value .. i have a code solved with jquery, but how to solve this with angularjs?? 
[JSBin Link to Edit](https://jsbin.com/nesoruwofu/edit?html,js,output)

**AngularJS**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
//Code goes here//
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div>
  <button>Feed</button>
  <button>the</button>
  <button>Input</button>
</div>
<input type="text" value="click a button">
 
  </body>

</html>
```

**Solved with jQuery**

```js
var actualButton;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  actualButton = $(this);
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
});
$("input").on('keyup', function(e){
  if(actualButton === undefined)
    return;

  actualButton.text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a combination of data-binding technics with ngModel and ngClick. Maybe something like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>angular.module('demo', []);</script>

<div ng-app="demo">
    <div>
        <button ng-click="i = 1" ng-init="button1 = 'Feed'">{{ button1 }}</button>
        <button ng-click="i = 2" ng-init="button2 = 'the'">{{ button2 }}</button>
        <button ng-click="i = 3" ng-init="button3 = 'Input'">{{ button3 }}</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="this['button' + i]" placeholder="click a button">    
</div>
```

Comment: hey hi i have a small doubt, input is in a page and buttons are in another page, i given route to those 2pages,, where data binding is not happening between them.. is there any changes to solve??

Comment: This is important detail. Because your two pages are in different scopes basically the solution needs to use some sort of common scope or service. You use ngRouter/uiRouter?

Comment: can u give me a suggestion that how to give a service to the above code .. ?

Comment: Here is a simple version with ngRouter. Should be the same for uiRouter. http://plnkr.co/edit/aiVbeJfa24LI6WUHhpCe?p=preview

Comment: u given me great valueable information.. but con't we bind values without using ng-repeat?? i have only static buttons,,

Comment: hey sry sry,, i didn't c ur code totally,, sorry, thank you so much for ur great answer, tnx alot

Answer (score 2):

Simply you could add a `ng-click` function over button, pass `$event` object with it. So that you could access the DOM on which event gets fired.

But I Personally don't use this method like I trying to access DOM directly inside a controller.

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="buttonClick($event)">Feed</button>
  <button ng-click="buttonClick($event)">the</button>
  <button ng-click="buttonClick($event)">Input</button>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" value="click a button">
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputValue = 'click a button';
    $scope.buttonClick = function(event){
        console.log(event);
        $scope.inputValue = event.target.innerText;
    };
});
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9waDYMgaEWnOuh72Iml?p=preview)

Angular approach would be you could render the button using `ng-repeat` array, and have those button inside you scope itself. And pass the button name from the click object and assign it to `inputValue` scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="$parent.selected = $index" ng-repeat="button in buttons">{{button.text}}</button>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="buttons[selected || 0].text" value="click a button">
```

**Code**

```
$scope.buttons = [{text: 'Feed', id: '1'}, {text: 'the', id: '2'}, {text: 'Input', id: '3'}];
```

[**Angular way Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GtM31xIWY5WNRvsvO8jJ?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParker yeah :) finally u did it .. i know u r always rocking :) thank u very much .. :)

Comment: @PankajParker yeah Sure .. :)

Comment: @PankajParker hey hi Pankaj i have a small doubt, input is in a page and buttons are in another page, i given route to those 2pages,, where data binding is not happening between them.. is there any changes to solve??

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [PLUNKER DEMO LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/wKh6WqGgAgLa284fRK4m?p=preview)

used `ng-click`, `ng-model` and `ng-change`

in Html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="setText($event)">Feed</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="setText($event)">the</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="setText($event)">Input</button>
 </div>
 <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeButtonText()">
</body>
```

and controller:

```
  $scope.textVal = 'click a button';
  $scope.seletetedEvent = {};
  $scope.setText = function(element) {
    console.log(element);
    $scope.seletetedEvent = element;
     $scope.textVal = element.currentTarget.innerHTML;
  };
  $scope.changeButtonText = function(){
    $scope.seletetedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
  };
```

Comment: sry,, not working ur code properly,, can u pls check it once again ?

Comment: click on any button then set button text in input and then if change input text then change clicked button text. can you visit demo link pls?

Comment: hey hi i have a small doubt, input is in a page and buttons are in another page, i given route to those 2pages,, where data binding is not happening between them.. is there any changes to solve??

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to do anything, just bind the same $scope variable to both textbox and button,

**View:**

```
 <input  ng-model="name" id="txtname" />
 <button class="button button-full button-light" >{{name}}</button>
```

Here is the Working **[`PlunkerApp`](https://plnkr.co/edit/T5NUPmf6HiyyKotYIWqf?p=preview)**

Comment: i know that data binding.. but my requirement is not that.. i want to show selected button value into a input text box..

Comment: you mean to take the element name dynamically and pass?

Comment: in ur code selected button value showing in inputbox, but where we change the text, have to change button value to ... but in ur code data is not binding between them..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102586/discussion-between-vijju-sena-and-sajeetharan).